# Is there a tool to view merged revisions in Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

Are there any tools out there, free or otherwise, that will show, in a graphical fashion, merges from one branch into another? What I have in mind would be similar to TortoiseSVN's revision graph, but with additional notation and lines to indicate merges from one line of development into another.

If such tools exist, which do you prefer and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the [RevTree plugin for Trac](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/RevtreePlugin).

Sorry, I cannot personally vouch for it, but it does claim to do what you want.  There are a number of limitations, so read the "Limitations" section carefully.

<sub>Disclosure: I am one of the Trac devs</sub>

Comment: This looks like what I am after, with a bit of tweaking, I think I can get it to work. If you have any more info on it, please share! I will post my results once I have some, good or bad.

Comment: While a bit more work that I was hopping for, since it needs all of Trac to work, this tool showed me the results I wanted in a pretty comprehensible format.

Answer (score 1):

At least I can say that we have already implemented "merge arrows" in our development version of SmartSVN. It should be available in a couple of weeks. Refer to [this blog posting](http://blog.syntevo.net/2009/08/18/1250617320000.html) for details.

Comment: Is there a free version of your tool? I could not determine that from the site.